# Button in popup doesn't work - chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, popup, onclicklistener, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've tried every solution I found here but nothing worked.
I only need this button to open my options.html page in a new tab.

Here is manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Block Site With Images",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      {
        "resources": [ "options.html" ],
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
      }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "html/popup.html",
        "default_title": "Block_Site"
    }
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body style="width: 100px;">
    <button type="button" id="options-page">Open Options</button>
    <script src="src/popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

popup.js

```
let openPageButton = document.getElementById("options-page");

openPageButton.addEventListener('click', myfunction);

function myfunction(){
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': "html/options.html" } )
}
```

I've tried different ways to do this myFunction method.
I've also tried this method:

```
console.log("chrome-extension://"+chrome.runtime.id+"/options.html");
chrome.tabs.query({url:"chrome-extension://"+chrome.runtime.id+"/options.html"}, function(tabs){
    if(tabs.length==0){
        window.open("options.html");
    }else{
        chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[0].id, null, function(){
        });
    }
});
```

which didn't work.

Edit: I've checked the devtools of the popup and it says "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" in line 1 in popup.js
I couldn't find a solution for this. I tried changing the button id from `options-page` to `options_page` thinking this is the reason but no luck.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you, I've looked in the devtools, see the edited question. I also tried Norio's solution which didn't work.

Comment: Found the solution, for some reason it didn't work when I've put the `popup.html` in a separate folder, I moved the file and now it works.

Comment: The problem in the original code can be fixed by adding `/` before `html/`.